# pyqt - QFileSystemModel without subdirectories?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt

is possible to make a `QFileSystemModel` in a `QTreeWidget` only showing folders in a path without their subfolders? also, can i get the folders size (with anything in them) using `QFileSystemModel`?

this is my code filtering to only folders:

```
m_index = r"C:/folder"

model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
model.setRootPath(m_index)
model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.Dirs|QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)

view = QtGui.QTreeView()
view.setModel(model)
view.setColumnHidden(2, True)
view.setColumnHidden(3, True)
view.setRootIndex(model.index(m_index))
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to get folder sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, `view.setItemsExpandable(False)` did the job...